# Configure SourceTree with Gitlab SSH

Tags: ssh, gitlab, sourcetree

I've already trying to set gitlab few days with SourceTree , you can explain it step by step? I can not find the solution.

Bye and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward.

1. Go to **File -> New / Clone** and it'll bring to the front the SourceTree repo info where you can add new repos.
2. Click **New Repository** and then **Clone from URL**
   [image]
3. Enter the URL of your **GitLab** repository, and below it the location where you want to save this repo on your computer and name of the repository if you want to name it differently.

[image]

4. A window will popup asking ask you for your GitLab username and password

And that's it. The GitLab repo will be cloned.

In case you are wondering where you get your project's URL on GitLab, it looks like this on GitLab when you click on your project:

[image]